# Onclick function not working after class is added with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, onclick, liquid

With JQuery I have added a class to 8 links. Now I want that if you click on it, a command will be executed.
That is the problem because it does not work.

Did I do something wrong here? or is this just not possible?

My JQuery:

```
(function ($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').find('a').addClass('filterchoice');
});

  $(".filterchoice").on("click", function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    console.log('Working');
});
})(jQuery);
```

And my html:

```
<div class="ticket-filter" id="ticket-filter-container">
  <div id="ticket-toolbar">
    <div class="dropdown" id="ticket-filters">
      <a href="#" class="list-lead dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        All Tickets <i class="caret"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li class="selected">
        <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">All Tickets</a>
        </li>
        <li>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Open or Pending</a>
        </li>
        <li
        ><a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Resolved or Closed</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ticket-sub-toolbar">
      <span id="ticket-sort" class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li class="selected">
          <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Date Created</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Last Modified</a>
          </li>
          <li>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Status</a>
          </li>
          <li class="divider"></li>
          <li>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Ascending</a>
          </li>
          <li class="selected">
          <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Descending</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <a class="dropdown-toggle help-text" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          Sorted by <b> Date Created</b>
          <i class="caret"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I make this website with Freshdesk, I cannot change this code myself.
This is the code in Freshdesk:

```
{% snippet ticket_filters %}
```

I don't know if you can use this, but Freshdesk uses the liquid Template Engine

I also made a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lzs80ayk/1/)

Comment: The problem is because you try to add the event handler *before* you add the class. You need to restructure the JS slightly: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/3wtmxp05/.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan That explains a lot, thank you!

Answer (score 2):

If you write your function like this: `jQuery("selector").on('click', function() {})`, then **jQuery will bind the event handlers to the currently available objects that it selects with the selector**.

If you want to handle dynamically added selectors, then you have to use a little more verbose syntax: `jQuery("staticSelector").on('click', 'dynamicSelector', function() {})`.

In your case, the difference is minimal:

```
$("body").on("click", ".filterchoice", function() {
  alert("Handler for .click() called.");
});
```

Bind your click handler to the `<body>` (that surely exists), and then always react to any click event on `.filterchoice`.

It's in jQuery docs: https://api.jquery.com/on/#on-events-selector-data-handler

Example on the page referenced jQuery doc page:

> An event-delegation approach attaches an event handler to only one
>   element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level
>   (from the clicked tr to tbody):
>
> $( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {   console.log(
>   $( this ).text() ); });

Here's your fiddle imported into a snippet, and modified as described above:

```js
(function($) {
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('ul.dropdown-menu').find('a').addClass('filterchoice');
  });

  $("body").on("click", ".filterchoice", function() {
    alert("Handler for .click() called.");
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ticket-filter" id="ticket-filter-container">
  <div id="ticket-toolbar">
    <div class="dropdown" id="ticket-filters">
      <a href="#" class="list-lead dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
        All Tickets <i class="caret"></i>
      </a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
        <li class="selected">
          <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">All Tickets</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Open or Pending</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Resolved or Closed</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
    <div id="ticket-sub-toolbar">
      <span id="ticket-sort" class="dropdown">
        <ul class="dropdown-menu " role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
          <li class="selected">
          <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
      <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Date Created</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Last Modified</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Status</a>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Ascending</a>
      </li>
      <li class="selected">
        <span class="icon ticksymbol"></span>
        <a href="#" data-loading-box="#ticket-list" data-method="get" data-remote="true" data-response-type="script">Descending</a>
      </li>
      </ul>
      <a class="dropdown-toggle help-text" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">
          Sorted by <b> Date Created</b>
          <i class="caret"></i>
        </a>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

You don't need to restructure your code.

Although I think @RoryMcCrossan is right - your code should be a bit restructured, it's not because of this problem. **When you load data or add DOM element dynamically, the restructuring won't solve your "not working" problem, but the delegated handler will** (so you'll have to use the more verbose syntax).